# Py3.4 IMAPLib Login... 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, imaplib

Using imaplib, I'm trying to connect to a mailserver.
When I include the password as just a normal string: 'password'
It connects fine.  But I'm trying to slightly obfuscate my password, so I previously had run it through b64encode, and then used b64decode in the login:

```
#Works:
mail.login('myloginname', 'myPassword')

#Doesn't Work:
mail.login('myloginname', base64.b64decode('Ja3rHsnakhdgkhervc'))
# or
mail.login('myloginname', bytes(base64.b64decode('Ja3rHsnakhdgkhervc')))
```

...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testing.py", line 15, in <module>
    mail.login('myloginname', bytes(base64.b64decode('Ja3rHsnakhdgkhervc')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 536, in login
    typ, dat = self._simple_command('LOGIN', user, self._quote(password))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 1125, in _quote
    arg = arg.replace('\\', '\\\\')
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a `bytes` object for the password, not a `str` value, because that's what `base64.b64decode()` returns.

You'd have to *decode* that value to a string:

```
 base64.b64decode('Ja3rHsnakhdgkhervc').decode('ascii')
```

The exception is caused by the `bytes.replace()` method, which expects `bytes` arguments. Since `'\\'` and `'\\\\'` are `str` objects, you get a traceback at `args.replace('\\', '\\\\')` only because `args` is a `bytes` object:

```
>>> b'foo'.replace('\\', '\\\\')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>> 'foo'.replace('\\', '\\\\')
'foo'
```

Comment: Ha!  I'd read so many posts about Py3 wanting bytes instead of strings, I didn't even think about casting it in the other direction.  Worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: New to Python and didn't understand the error message correctly.  Assumed that when it said 'str' doesn't support, it was seeing that I was passing a string rather than that it was looking for a string.